# Strange npm behavior when installing packages like grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp, bower

I run the following command in my `bash` and I get the related results:

```
merianos@merianos-desktop:~$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
```

and

```
merianos@merianos-desktop:~$ grunt
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I also have try to install `bower` and `gulp` but again, when I try to execute them, I get a message related to the `grunt` above.

Can someone please help me ?

Just to know, I just installed `Ubuntu 15.04`. I don't know if that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu package `nodejs` provide a binary as a `/usr/bin/nodejs`, not a `/usr/bin/node`, so most of cli tools can't find it. To solve the problem you need to make a symlink:

```
sudo ln -sT /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :) By the way I just was ready to close the question, because I found the answer from another post, while I was trying to re-install the NodeJS. Thanks a lot !! :)